# How to delete stuck batch?

Tags: 7, batch-operations

What is a good way to delete a stuck batch in Drupal 7?

It is on a production server, we are using the Background Batch module so it shows us which one it is at admin/config/system/batch/overview.[image]

I know I can just run a query and delete that row from the DB but wondering about other cleanup I should do too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach (if you don't want to run sql-statements directly) would be [Queue UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/queue_ui):

> - View queues and number of items
> - Developers can define meta info about queues they create and process
> - Process queue with Batch API
> - Process queue during cron
> - Remove leases
> - Delete queue

[image]

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something quick and easy to run on a production server without committing new code. Does this delete batches though or just queues?

Comment: batches are treated as queues, so yes.

Comment: 4 years later, I just accepted this answer! I remember now that this worked well for that project, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In my case the batch ID is 5166:

`DELETE FROM batch WHERE bid IN (5166);`

In our case we are using Better Batch and we also needed to run:

`DELETE FROM better_batch WHERE bid IN (5166);` otherwise we received an infinite redirect message in Chrome "too many redirects".

source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1627850#comment-6142774